# Calculate the rotation of image view animation according to speed

Tags: core-animation, velocity, image-rotation

I am creating animation using 60 image and also creating animation performed through touch move events.
I am also calculate speed (velocity) of touch move points.

And now i want to perform animation like if speed is fast then animated images rotate like cycle and automatic stop according to time and speed.

If any one has an idea to how to calculate and how to manage this interesting stuff.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to simulate the way a motorcycle leans into curves? You'd need to calculate the angular momentum. Take a look at this wiki article:

[Angular momentum wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But sir how can i apply this equation and all this terms in my example because in article it create so confusion. So sir please another time help me please. I got a speed of touches move.